# TypeError when reading "$(...).toast"

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, django-channels

I'm coding a web app with Django Channels and WebSockets, and I want to dynamically create the bootstrap toasts (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/toasts/) when a WebSocket connection is open. The problem is that an error is raised "*Uncaught TypeError: $(...).toast is not a function*". So the question is **how to read the** `$('.toast').toast('show');` **line in** `Socket.onopen` (*I'm not really into jQuery*). I'll be thankful if you have any ideas?

Here is a part of the js file:

```
 var Socket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(ws_path)
    Socket.onopen = function (e) {
      newToast();
      $('.toast').toast('show');
     };

    function newToast(data) {
        // create Bootstrap toast element
     };
```

In the head of html file, Bootstrap and jQuery are loaded:

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
```

PS: I've already tried to replace the dollar sign with jQuery. Same error : *Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(..)* ...

Comment: Sounds like `$` is assigned something else than jQuery or the bootstrap JS library is not loaded at the time. Try `console.log($)` and see what that gives you.

Comment: `console.log($)` gives me "f (a,b) {return new n.fn.init(a,b)}"

Comment: @Yassine That output looks like your `$` is aliased to jQuery correctly. Is your `bootstrap.js` loading?

Comment: It's been ages since I've used jQuery, but that looks like a the jQuery method. What if you try `console.log($('.toast'))` and `console.log($('.toast').toast('show'))`. First one will return `length: 1` if the element exists. Second one should give you an error if Boostrap js is not loaded.

Comment: @thingEvery Yes it is. I'm using a CDN and the toast works when I just copy the code!

Comment: Can you do other stuff to that `.toast` div? Maybe something like: `$('.toast').css('border', '3px solid red');`  If that doesn't work either, your script might be firing before the DOM is ready.

Comment: @Kordonme so the first one returns " n.fn.init [div.toast, prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: '.toast'] " and second one gives me the Uncaught error.. So that means that the Bootstrap js is not loaded ? how come since it's working when I just write `$('.toast').toast('show')` outside of `Socket.onopen` and copy the toast code ?

Comment: @thingEvery it seems to work when I do something else like what you proposed.  At least no error is raised..

Comment: I updated my answer again. Check it out.

Comment: Please add the `script` tags with which you include bootstrap and jQuery, and clarify where you have those tags (in `head`?). It is necessary to load jQuery before bootstrap. Are you sure you did not get any other error *preceding* the one you quoted?

Comment: @trincot I don't think it's the problem since it's working when I just copy the toast code and `$('.toast').toast('show');` in js file. I've edited the post.

Comment: Well, so far I did not pinpoint what the problem is. Just trying to reproduce your case ;-)

Comment: Unrelated, but why do you load jQuery "slim" version first, but then load the full jQuery in the next line? The first of the two is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes you're right. I guess I was doing some tests before and I kept the first line there.

Comment: OK problem resolved. You've given me a hint @trincot I found out that, due to the same tests, I had loaded jQuery after the script too.. I've deleted it and it's working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue... The only solution that I could find was using google's CDN

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```